# How to write RLIKE in zend framework 3?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-db-select, rlike

I have a raw query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM caps WHERE `items` RLIKE '[[:<:]]20003[[:>:]]';
```

I've converted this query to 'zf3 select' format. I'm using `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` and extending `TableGateway`. Here is the converted zf3 query

```
$this->select(function (Select $s) use ($itemId) {
   $s->where(new Expression(sprintf('(items RLIKE "[[:<:]]`%d`[[:>:]]")', $itemId)));
});
```

I'm not getting any error when I run the page. But when I print the 'resultSet' the `where` part is not appending to the query. How can I write this up in zf3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I just use `expression` with my `where` clause. It's working fine now. Here is the part of my new query.

```
$s->where->expression('items RLIKE "[[:<:]]'.$itemId.'[[:>:]]"');
```